# Two variables set to null inside ( ) of function

Tags: php, cakephp

In my model I have this

```
function pieChart($conditions = null) {
    //Get Data for PieChart
    $this->RecordDrug->virtualFields['sum'] ='COUNT(*)';
    $records = array();
    $records=$this->RecordDrug->find('list',
        array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'fields' => array( 'Drug.drug', 'sum'),
            'order' => array('sum' => 'desc'),
            'contain' => array( 'Drug', 'Record' ),
            'group'  => 'Drug.Drug'
            ));
    return $records;
}
```

Which basically means that when this function is called by it's self, there are no conditions set. So inside my controller, I am able to define a condition, if i'd like. I want to do the exact same thing except with

```
'limit' => $limit,
```

and I assume I need to set

```
$limit = null
```

Inside the parenthesis of the function. I've tried & and , and $limit,$conditions = null
but neither of these options worked. I am not too experience with OOP but I assume there is a way to do this?

EDIT:

Updated code, Still not working. The first varialbe that comes inside the functions parenthesis is the one that works, the second one just act's like it's not there

Model:

```
function pieChart($limit = null, $conditions = null) {
    //Get Data for PieChart
    $this->RecordDrug->virtualFields['sum'] ='COUNT(*)';
    $records = array();
    $records=$this->RecordDrug->find('list',
        array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'fields' => array( 'Drug.drug', 'sum','Record.unit'),
            'order' => array('sum' => 'desc'),
            'limit' => $limit,
            'contain' => array( 'Drug', 'Record' ),
            'group'  => 'Drug.Drug'
            ));
    debug($records);
    return $records;
}
```

Controller:

```
$conditions = array('Record.user_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'));
$pieChart = $this->Record->pieChart($conditions);
$this->set('output',$pieChart);
```

Even after this conditions variable, it does not only load the users data. If I were to remove '$limit = null' it will work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```
function pieChartTwo($limit = null, $conditions = null) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That.. worked. That is so weird because I tried the exact same thing as well, except conditions came first and then limit. Does the order really make a difference?

Comment: The order doesn't make any difference, `function pieChartTwo($conditions = null, $limit = null) { ... }` works. What error did you get when you tried ?

Comment: I wouldn't get an error, it would just act as if 'limit' didn't exist at all.

Comment: If you can reproduce the error, post the code in an edit below your question. You probably had a simple issue like case-sensitivity (`$limit` and `$Limit` are two different variables in PHP).

Comment: Hey again, I actually started working on my program and when I went to the page where my $conditions variable will be used, it wasn't doing anything. Which means that the first variable set to null works, but the second one acts like it's not there. That's why earlier my $limit wasn't working, because it was the second variable being set. I have no idea how to get around this.

Comment: Give us some code so we can reproduce this, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: Your problem is not in your function, it is in your function call. When you call `$pieChart = $this->Record->pieChart($conditions);` your are not really passing your single parameter to `$condition`, you are passing it to `$limit`. Parameters are not bound by name, they are bound by order. You can either call it like `$pieChart = $this->Record->pieChart(null, $conditions);`, or reverse the parameters order (if you never intend to call with $limit alone), or create two funcs `pieChartWithLimit` and `pieChartWithCondition` that both call `pieChart($limit, null)` and `pieChart(null, $condition)`.

Comment: I never knew this. Thank you very much